# Jasmine test using spyon with $httpBackend not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, httpbackend, spyon

I am trying to write a jasmine test on some javascript using spyon over a method that uses $http. I have mocked this out using $httpBackend and unfortunately the spy doesn't seem to be picking up the fact the method has indeed been called post $http useage. I can see it being called in debug, so unsure why it reports it hasn't been called. I suspect I have a problem with my scope usage ? or order of $httpBackend.flush\verify ?:

**Code under test**

```
function FileUploadController($scope, $http, SharedData, uploadViewModel) {

   Removed variables for brevity
   .....

    $scope.pageLoad = function () {
        $scope.getPeriods();

        if ($scope.uploadViewModel != null && $scope.uploadViewModel.UploadId > 0) {
            $scope.rulesApplied = true;
            $scope.UploadId = $scope.uploadViewModel.UploadId;

            $scope.linkUploadedData();
        } else {
            $scope.initDataLinkages();
        }

    }


    $scope.initDataLinkages = function () {

        $http({ method: "GET", url: "/api/uploadhistory" }).
           success(function (data, status) {
               $scope.status = status;
               $scope.setUploadHistory(data);

           }).
         error(function (data, status) {
             $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
             $scope.status = status;
         });

    }

    $scope.setUploadHistory = function (data) {

        if ($scope.UploadId > 0) {
            $scope.currentUpload = data.filter(function (item) {
                return item.UploadId === $scope.UploadId;
            })[0];

            //Remove the current upload, to prevent scaling the same data!
            var filteredData = data.filter(function (item) {
                return item.UploadId !== $scope.UploadId;
            });
            var defaultOption = {
                UploadId: -1,
                Filename: 'this file',
                TableName: null,
                DateUploaded: null
            };

            $scope.UploadHistory = filteredData;

            $scope.UploadHistory.splice(0, 0, defaultOption);
            $scope.UploadHistoryId = -1;

            $scope.UploadTotal = $scope.currentUpload.TotalAmount;

        } else {
            $scope.UploadHistory = data;
        }
    }
```

**Test setup**

```
beforeEach(module('TDAnalytics'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_$rootScope_, $controller, _$httpBackend_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;

    var sharedData = { currentBucket: { ID: 1 } };

    controller = $controller('FileUploadController', { $scope: $scope, SharedData: sharedData, uploadViewModel: null }); 

    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/Periods').respond(periods);

    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/api/uploadhistory').respond(uploadHistory);


    $scope.mappingData = {
        FieldMappings: [testDescriptionRawDataField, testSupplierRawDataField],
        UserFields: [testDescriptionUserField, testSupplierUserField]
    };
}));

afterEach(function() {
    testDescriptionRawDataField.UserFields = [];
    testSupplierRawDataField.UserFields = [];
    testTotalRawDataField.UserFields = [];

    $httpBackend.flush();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});
```

**Working test:**

```
it('pageLoad should call linkUploadedData when user has navigated to the page via the Data Upload History and uploadViewModel.UploadId is set', function () {
    // Arrange
    spyOn($scope, 'linkUploadedData');
    $scope.uploadViewModel = {UploadId: 1};
    // Act
    $scope.pageLoad();

    // Assert
    expect($scope.rulesApplied).toEqual(true);
    expect($scope.linkUploadedData.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
});
```

**Test that doesn't work (but should. returns count-0 but is called)**

```
it('pageLoad should call setUploadHistory when data returned successfully', function () {
    // Arrange
    spyOn($scope, 'setUploadHistory');
    // Act
    $scope.initDataLinkages();

    // Assert
    expect($scope.setUploadHistory.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you call httpBackend.flush() after the expect, which means success is called after you do your tests. You must flush before the expect statement.

```
it('pageLoad should call setUploadHistory when data returned successfully',
inject(function ($httpBackend, $rootScope) {
    // Arrange
    spyOn($scope, 'setUploadHistory');
    // Act
    $scope.initDataLinkages();
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $rootScope.$digest()
    // Assert
       expect($scope.setUploadHistory.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
}));
```

You may need to remove the flush statement from after your tests, but it probably should not be there anyway because usually it's a core part of testing behaviour and should be before expect statements.